# Use Different OpenSSL for Apache

Tags: apache-httpd, compiling, openssl, dynamic-linking

I'm compiling Apache from source, and staticly linking `mod_ssl`. I'm looking to use a different version of OpenSSL to the system-installed version. I would like to do this in a way that doesn't affect the rest of the system, which is CentOS, as I would prefer to not change the core system's SSL version, used by other installed software that will continue to be managed by the package manager.

**How can I do this properly?**

I've tried compiling Apache `--with-ssl` which works fine for compiling it, but then it doesn't find it when trying to run it.

```
./httpd: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm thinking that perhaps I could set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when starting up Apache, which works fine, but not sure that's an appropriate approach. What's the recommended way to approach this? Is there a better way to add a directory for an alternative library search path?

Answer (score 5):

First, you should [get the desired version of **OpenSSL**](https://www.openssl.org/source/) and install it at a location where it will not interfere with your system version, e.g. `/opt`:

```
$ ./config \
    --prefix=/opt/openssl-VERSION \
    --openssldir=/opt/openssl-VERSION
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Next, get the latest [Apache 2.4.x](http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi), [APR and APR-Util](https://apr.apache.org/download.cgi) libraries. You will need to unpack all three packages into the same source tree, with the latter two in the location where Apache expects them. For example:

```
$ tar zxvf httpd-VERSION.tar.gz
$ cd httpd-VERSION/srclib/
$ tar zxvf ../../apr-VERSION.tar.gz
$ ln -s apr-VERSION/ apr
$ tar zxvf ../../apr-util-VERSION.tar.gz
$ ln -s apr-util-VERSION/ apr-util
```

Then, configure and install Apache. The `mod_ssl` module will be compiled statically, with all other modules dynamically, like this:

```
$ ./configure \
    --prefix=/opt/httpd \
    --with-included-apr \
    --enable-ssl \
    --with-ssl=/opt/openssl-VERSION \
    --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps \
    --enable-mods-static=ssl
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks

Comment: This worked for me, except I also had to build expat from source (https://github.com/libexpat) and provide an additional argument of `--with-expat=/usr/local/lib` to `configure`. I also included the `--enable-so` argument FWIW. Finally, I had to do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl-VERSION/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before i could start httpd.

Answer (score 2):

Add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the envvars file in the bin directory, this will then be used by apachectl.

Comment: That could work for a different build of the same version of OpenSSL, e.g. you have made local modifications to libopenssl-1.1, that'll work.  But it won't work to shift from 1.1.1 to 3.x.   For example, I have built httpd locally and `mod_ssl.so` looks for `libssl.so.3` and `libcrypto.so.3`.  But the binary installed from the RPM is looking for `libssl.so.1.1` and `libcrypto.so.1.1`.   Check the results of `ldd mod_ssl.so`.